# Custom PostType single page not working

Tags: wordpress

I searched and found that it was solved in some articles with the help of flush_rewrite_rules() but since I already use that function, that didn't solve my issue.

When I create a post under mytype, and click to "View Post", it redirects to 404.

I replaced my post type with "mytype" just to be read easier.

Thanks by now.

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_puzzle_init' );
/**
 * Register a puzzle post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_puzzle_init() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Puzzles', 'post type general name', 'domain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Puzzles', 'post type singular name', 'domain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Puzzles', 'admin menu', 'domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Puzzle', 'add new on admin bar', 'domain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'puzzle', 'domain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Puzzle', 'domain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Puzzle', 'domain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Puzzle', 'domain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Puzzle', 'domain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Puzzles', 'domain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Puzzle', 'domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Puzzle:', 'domain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Puzzles found.', 'domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Puzzles found in Trash.', 'domain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'puzzle' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 4,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-tablet',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'puzzle-category'),
        'taxonomies'         => array('puzzle-category')
    );

    register_post_type( 'puzzle', $args );

    flush_rewrite_rules();

}

add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'codex_puzzle_updated_messages' );

/**
 * puzzles update messages.
 *
 * See /wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php
 *
 * @param array $messages Existing post update messages.
 *
 * @return array Amended post update messages with new CPT update messages.
 */
function codex_puzzle_updated_messages( $messages ) {
    $post             = get_post();
    $post_type        = get_post_type( $post );
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    $messages['puzzle'] = array(
        0  => '', // Unused. Messages start at index 1.
        1  => __( 'puzzles updated.', 'domain' ),
        2  => __( 'Custom field updated.', 'domain' ),
        3  => __( 'Custom field deleted.', 'domain' ),
        4  => __( 'puzzle updated.', 'domain' ),
        /* translators: %s: date and time of the revision */
        5  => isset( $_GET['revision'] ) ? sprintf( __( 'puzzle restored to revision from %s', 'domain' ), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
        6  => __( 'puzzle published.', 'domain' ),
        7  => __( 'puzzle saved.', 'domain' ),
        8  => __( 'puzzle submitted.', 'domain' ),
        9  => sprintf(
            __( 'puzzle scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>.', 'domain' ),
            // translators: Publish box date format, see http://php.net/date
            date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i', 'domain' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) )
        ),
        10 => __( 'puzzle draft updated.', 'domain' )
    );

    if ( $post_type_object->publicly_queryable ) {
        $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );

        $view_link = sprintf( ' <a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $permalink ), __( 'View puzzle', 'domain' ) );

        if(isset($messages[ $post_type ])){

            if($post_type == "puzzle"){

                $messages[ $post_type ][1] .= $view_link;
                $messages[ $post_type ][6] .= $view_link;
                $messages[ $post_type ][9] .= $view_link;

                $preview_permalink = add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', $permalink );
                $preview_link = sprintf( ' <a target="_blank" href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $preview_permalink ), __( 'Preview puzzle', 'domain' ) );
                $messages[ $post_type ][8]  .= $preview_link;
                $messages[ $post_type ][10] .= $preview_link;

            }

        }

    }

    return $messages;
}

function register_puzzle_category() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'puzzle-category',
        'puzzle',
        array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'label'             => _("Puzzle Category", "domain"),  //Display name
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug'          => 'puzzle-category', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front'    => false // Don't display the category base before
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_puzzle_category');
```

Comment: The code, as you submitted it, does display the single page fine. I don't get a 404 error. This would suggest that either something outside of this code is causing the problem or you're looking at a cached error page.

Comment: Yes no problem with mytype, but when I change mytype with my actual type name (puzzle), single gives error. But when I set slug = "game", it still works great. Why? How? "Puzzle" can't be a reference word or something to break anything.

I'm not sure.. There's only one connection of puzzle word with the system, it's metabox side. I don't understand.

Comment: Go ahead and update your code above to the non-working version so that we can see what isn't working.

Comment: OK I changed the example code.

Comment: @t-turkey Everything working perfectly here. `_("Puzzle Category ..` should be `__`

Comment: Thanks Rahil, but that didn't solve, I really don't know why slug=>'puzzle' creates this problem. I'll try slug=>'game' for a while which works. Thanks for spending your time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'puzzle' ) to

'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'puzzle','with_front' => false ) in register_post_type function.

Comment: Thanks for the help but didn't work. I guess I'm confused for how to set single slug and archive slugs for post types. These might conflict with each other. How can I set archive slug for post type?